# For loop isn't working for ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Ok basically I am sort of new to `ArrayList` and i have to use it to make a program of getting some patients ID and then displaying it on the screen using objects and for loop. I did make the program but my loops aren't executing.
this is my program:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class patient$ {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<patientss> patient1 = new ArrayList<patientss>();
        Scanner src = new Scanner(System.in);
        int id, i, num;
        String name;
        int ages;
        System.out.println(" j");
        for (i = 0; i < patient1.size(); i++) {
            patientss xx = new patientss();
            System.out.println("Enter the patient's ID ");
            id = src.nextInt();
            xx.setId(id);
            patient1.add(xx);
        }
        patientss tt = new patientss();
        for (i = 0; i < patient1.size(); i++) {
            tt = patient1.get(i);
            System.out.println(tt.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my `patientss` class:

```
package samplee.java;
public class patientss {
    int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it *is* "executing", although it may not be doing so as you wish.  Since you don't give any details about how it is working or how you want it to, can't say much more than that.

Comment: Which for loop isn't executing? The one after the println(" j")? Is there a reason you'd expect it to execute? What happens if you replace that println(" j") with println(patientss.size())?

Comment: "i<patient1.size();" in the first for loop shouldn't even execute since there is nothing in the list... also in the second loop you can just do patient1.get(i).getId() rather than assigning it

Comment: yea u r right thanks. but how do i fill up the arraylist for this program:/  what are the commands or codes i need to use and where? sorry i am new to arraylist so its sort of confusing for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your loops are running on an empty ArrayList, so the `size()` method will return 0. Try changing the `size()` method in the first for loop to however many `patientss` you want to add.

Comment: ok i tried that and it worked.. So i guess the problem is that my arraylist is empty.. Tho what are the statements i should write in order to have something on my arraylist in this case then? :/ sorry I just recently started arraylist so its a bit confusing for me.

Comment: So, when you initialize an ArrayList, it doesn't have an initial size (unless you initialize it with elements in it). So, because it's not like a normal array (which has a defined length that won't change) but instead has a variating amount of elements, the `size()` method returns how many elements are actually inside the ArrayList, not the "size" of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your first loop is iterating over an empty ArrayList.

Since the point of this loop seems to be to be *adding* things to that list, the number of iterations should be controlled by how many things you want to add to it, not how many are already in it.  For example, the loop could continue as long as `patient1.size()<N`, where `N` is the number of items you want to add.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution. Replace the first loop with my code.

```
Boolean leave = false;
while (!leave) {
    patientss xx = new patientss();
    System.out.println("Enter the patient's ID ");
    System.out.println("-1 to finish entering");
    id = src.nextInt();
    if (id != -1) {
        xx.setId(id);
        patient1.add(xx);
    } else { leave = true; } //Escape the while loop.
}
```